# changing dropdown display text by clicking on another button in Vuejs

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, vue.js, drop-down-menu

I have a dropdown:

```
            <BaseDropdown
              @input="value => statusSelected(value)"
              name="Status"
              ref="status"
              label="Status:"
              rules="required"
              :options="statusItems"
              v-model="status"
              value="status"
              placeholder="Please select a status"
            />
```

And a button:

```
<button class="edit" @click="editComment(status)">Edit </button>
```

The value of status parameter is `"note"`. I have this function:

```
editComment(status){
      this.status = status
}
```

It changes the value of v-model to `"note"` since I can see it in the log but the display text of the dropdown doesn't change. What should I do to change the display value of dropdown text?

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful to see the BaseDropdown component or have a screenshot to visualize what you mean. There's not enough info to see what that component is doing.

What I am seeing though is you are going to need another variable and a computed Property. `status` and `editStatus`.

```
computed:{
  displayStatus(){
    return this.editStatus || this.status;
  }
},
methods: {
  editComment(status){
      this.editStatus = status
  }
}
```

```
<BaseDropdown
              @input="value => statusSelected(value)"
              name="Status"
              ref="status"
              label="Status:"
              rules="required"
              :options="statusItems"
              v-model="status"
              value="displayStatus"
              placeholder="Please select a status"
            />
```

This is just a guess because I can not see all the details.